# How to switch from python interpreter to C++ compiler on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently installed anaconda and added it to my visual studio code. I had previously installed C++
but now after setting up python interpreter on visual studio code i can't figure out how to switch back to my C++ compiler
Does anyone knows how to?

Edit:

My vs code folder looks like:

```
->.vscode
   ->settings.json (1)
->c_cpp_properties.json
->launch.json
->settings.json (2)
```

My launch.json

```
 {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

My settings.json (2):

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "right"
    },
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "[cpp]": {
    
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
    }
}
```

Settings.json (1):

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\HP\\.conda\\envs\\myenv\\python.exe"
}
```

My c_cpp_properties file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compileCommands": ""
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I think i have messed up my settings.json but i don't understand much about vs code yet so i can't figure out how to fixed it.

Comment: select a different launch configuration

Comment: If you have the launch.json under .vscode folder and it configured correctly, then you can press on F5 to start debugging, so C++ compiler will start.

Comment: Install the C++ extension. You can install the C/C++ extension by searching for 'c++' in the Extensions view, just create or add `c_cpp_properties.json` file which will include compiler path and other includepath thats it...

Comment: @ullaskunder it already exists.... i will attach that too.. actually i was using c++ compiler before but after adding python i think i messed up somewhere

Comment: just an example about setting up compiler to environment and vs code have a look u'll get the idea [repo link](https://github.com/ullaskunder3/Solution-to-graphics.h) and a suggestion create separate workspace for every language